# Nullable properties in index transform

Tags: ravendb

I am trying to do a fairly simple index and transform that is copying a `DateTime?` property from the document to the projection.

If there are any documents where the property is null it produces the following error:

`System.InvalidOperationException: The transform results function failed.
Doc 'people/3', Error: Cannot convert type 'Raven.Abstractions.Linq.DynamicNullObject' to 'System.DateTime?'`

see gist: https://gist.github.com/pdegenhardt/5022737

Is this a bug or am I doing something wrong?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This test is working for me:  https://gist.github.com/ayende/5023050

You didn't mention a build, but you need to try the latest.

Comment: Damn. I had updated client to latest unstable build but it was running against an old IIS hosted server. Updating the server to the latest build fixed the problem. Thanks for your help and congratulations on a wonderful product!